# What is the performance overhead of IFNULL in the select statement of mysql 5.7+ query

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

I've recently made an upgrade to a mysql query performed by my web server when serving request. There are two main permutations of the query, one will typically be limited to returning 500 rows and another will be limited to a particular value of a column (and is properly indexed) resulting in 5-10k results.

The original query looks like this...

```sql
SELECT v1, v2, v3 FROM t1;
```

The new query looks like the following.

```sql
SELECT v1, v2, v3, IFNULL(t2.u1, 0), IFNULL(t2.u2, '')
    FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Changing the query lead to maxing out my database connections and subsequently timing out most of my web server requests.

Also note, `t2` is currently empty, so every `IFNULL` should be resolved as the second parameter.

The main question(s) a.) is `IFNULL` expensive b.) does it somehow prevent efficient caching of queries?

Comment: *Changing the query lead to maxing out my database connections and subsequently timing out most of my web server requests.* The source of your problem is JOIN, not IFNULL().

Comment: Please provide your index definition(s) in the post.

Comment: When asking questions about query optimization, you should show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table in the query, so we can see the columns, data types, indexes, and constraints you have defined. Also run `EXPLAIN <query>` and show the result so we can see how the MySQL optimizer is choosing to use indexes. Help us to help you!

Comment: Thank you @BillKarwin. I ran the `EXPLAIN` query and got the following field in extra for one of my joins `Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)`.  I was able to find a number of good answers for this on stackoverflow. It appears my issue is linked the a known issue [mysql issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69721)

Comment: Usually that can be fixed by adding an index in the joined table. That's why I asked you to supply the CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN reports. But if you're satisfied with the unoptimized query, that's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this list of **overheads**:

- Overhead for a statement
- Overhead for a row
- Overhead for a function

Those are in order starting with the most overhead.  That is, the function overhead is insignificant in the big picture; don't worry about it.

See also `COALESCE()`.

**Caching**

With Engine=InnoDB, the main cache is the "buffer_pool"; `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of available RAM.  *All* actions on rows happen in the buffer_pool:

1. Read block(s) from disk (if not already in cache)
2. Find the row(s) in the block(s)
3. Fetch (SELECT) or modify row(s)
4. Eventually write the block back to disk (if modified)

Since you are asking about `SELECT`, only steps 1,2,3 are relevant.  Furthermore, if you keep Selecting the same row (or nearby rows), step 1 is not repeated.

Note: This does not mention any impact of function calls.

Note: On a cold system (nothing in the cache), the first `SELECT` will be slower due to step 1.  After that the same or 'similar' queries will be faster (sometimes 10x faster).

Comment:  `ON t1.id = t2.id` Do you have two tables with identical `PRIMARY KEYS`?  Why?

The main way to have good performance in a JOIN is to have suitable indexes.  Let's see the *real* query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables being Joined.

The BNL mentioned in a comment is an internal "caching" to speed up *certain* Joins.  You have little control over its use.  It refers to fetching all the stuff needed from a secondary table and storing it in an in-memory hash.  It only applies when Joining.  Function calls are not involved (in your example).

If a function (eg, IFNULL) were used in `ON` or `WHERE`, it is likely to prevent the use of an otherwise suitable Index.  (cf not "sargable")